# SMPTE to MIDI Time Code (MTC)

Tags: time, byte, midi, timecodes, nibble

I'm trying to convert SMPTE to MTC.
I've been looking everywhere to get some information about MTC and got pretty far, except for this last one step. I'm not entirely sure how I should achieve this, since MTC makes use of high and low nibbles, with which I'm not familiar with.

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: What exactly is "this last one step"?

Comment: Converting the SMPTE timecode to MTC, so I can send the correct Quarter Frame to Ableton Live. I need the low and high nibble from the frames, seconds, minutes and hours and put them in a format like 0xnn (where the first n represents a frame (0 or 1), second (2 or 3), minute (4 or 5) or hour (6 or 7) and the second n represents the low/high nibble)

Comment: What programming language are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: I'm using Python. I'm just trying to get my head around this. What I think I need to do is convert the given integer to a binary, split the binary in a low and high nibble and convert the nibble to a hexadecimal.